# Does hub diameter or hub size have a notice able effect on the aerodynamic performance of a wheel set?

Tags: aerodynamics

If you were to change the rear hub on your hypothetical or real zipp 808 wheel set to a large diameter internal gear hub like a shimano alfine or a rohlhoff hub would there be a measure able aero dynamic effect?

Comment: Is it currently geared?

Comment: yes, just for the sake of a real world comparison

Comment: Then you need to compare the larger hub to hub cassette and derailleur.  The larger hub will have less drag.

Answer (score 1):

There would be a measurable decrease in drag from removing external dérailleurs and gearing, however I would guess that the power loss through an internally geared hub would make such a setup slower rather than faster.

(I have no sources for this)

Comment: I would like to comment that rohloff themselves state 'the working efficiency of the Rohloff SPEEDHUB 500/14 is brought up to 96% (for gears #1 to #7) and 98% (for gears #8 to #14)'and they then go on to say 'This working efficiency is comparable to a derailleur gear system. Common 7-speed gear hubs are reaching only a working efficiency of approx. 90% (gear #1) and 98% (direct drive gear)'. Though I will admit this is hardly impartial and taken straight from there website: http://www.rohloff.de/en/technology/efficiency/

Comment: I thought the question was about aero drag, making the efficiency of the gear train irrelevant? IMO losing the derailleurs will help, a larger hub is very unlikely to make it more aero... until the hub almost hits the rim :).

Comment: It is about aero drag, but whilst the improvement would be measurable...